# grep alternative in perl

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I am using the `grep` and `sort` commands to get a unique list of all variable names in a file. However It doesn't work with Perl.

#### /tmp/a.txt

```
 Hello
 A
 A
 $TEST
 $ABC
 $HELLO
 $HELLO
```

#### Unix Command

```
grep -o '\$\<[^/ ]*\>' /tmp/a.txt | sort -u
$ABC
$HELLO
$TEST
```

Perl

```
my @Var = ` grep -o /\/$\<[^/ ]*\>/ /tmp/a.txt | sort -u`;
```

Comment: Why do you want to write bash code in Perl? It's nearly always better to use the Perl language to solve a problem rather than shelling out to a lesser language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets a lot easier when you use Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my %seen;
say for sort grep { chomp; /\$/ and ! $seen{$_}++ } <>;
```

If you save this program in a file called `grepit` in your current directory then you can call it like this from a bash command prompt:

```
$ ./grepit /tmp/a.txt
```

If you want, you can spread it out a bit more:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my %seen;
my @vars;

while (<>) {

  next unless /\$/;

  chomp;

  next if $seen{$_}++;

  push @vars, $_;
}

for ( sort @vars ) {
  say;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's a great advertisement for Perl; are you showing off? The first program looks like an awk solution preceded by a bunch of boilerplate. It also prints any line that contains at least one dollar sign, which can be easily improved

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; use warnings; use Data::Dumper;
my $cmd = 'grep -o "\$\<[^/ ]*\>" a.txt | sort -u';
my @var= `$cmd`; 
chomp(@var);
print Dumper(\@var);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$VAR1 = [
    '$ABC',
    '$HELLO',
    '$TEST'
];
```